# How to get mail nsf file name after user login in domino

Tags: java, lotus-domino, identify

I need to get user's nsf file name after he logins in the system, for opening that mail file. Name is required since I am getting 4269 & 4457 error on login then I have to give mail file name for login on non home server. Plz help??

Comment: So what is the question? Opening the mail file can be done by: notesDatabase.OpenMail.

Answer (score 1):

First place to lookup the user is the Servers "names.nsf" file, there you have the all Users important properties (mailfile, roaming files. web-password etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get user mail file information using @NameLookup, which will work with all of the server's directories: http://extranet2.ahrq.gov/help/help7_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/ceae65480a1a1e188525704a003fefa5?OpenDocument . You could find the mail file using, I believe, @NameLookup([Exhaustive]; "Joe Smith"; "MailFile"). The last parameter can be switched to anything else in the user document, including other pertinent fields like "MailServer" and "MailSystem" (I believe those are the field names).